# three level deep Jquery sortbable Issue

Tags: jquery, nested, jquery-ui-sortable

```
 I have three levels of jQuery sortable divs,
 all having draggable, droppable and sortable features.

 The moment I put the the third sortable div inside the second div,
 and drag them  around, i get this error : 

>HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': 
The new child element contains the parent./jquery.js
```

I know this is because the child is trying to put the control in itself. 
 But, does anyone have any other tricks up their sleeve     that they can help me out with, 
so that this limitation of jQuery sortable can be cleverly overcome?

```
 I want to extend this http://jsfiddle.net/ExLqv/12
 with three levels of nesting.
```

Comment: I would suggest listing the plugins you are aware of to prevent others suggesting as such.  Also try putting a snippet of your code to give us something to work with.

Comment: Mine is on the same lines as this one , but one level depper https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231678/jquery-sortable-nested-sortable-divs?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Best code example of 2 levels is this : http://jsfiddle.net/ExLqv/12/